# web page displayed in a little space in the screen on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, html

I have a problem whe I want to display web page. I use

```
BrowserField bwrField = new BrowserField(config);
            add(bwrField);
bwrField.requestContent(URI.create(url.toSring());
```

I can run many page web with this code and the page is opened by the default browser in simulator but I have a problem with one page that diplay in little space in the screen.
How Can I manipulate the width and the hight of the swreen browser Field. 
There is another method like the default browser to run this page

[image]

Comment: Take one VerticalFieldManager and set width and height in sublayout() method. Then add browserField to that VFM. Enough.

Comment: Can you explain me by showing an exemple. I'm beginner in BB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your broswerfiled inside your manager and try overriding the managers sublayout method.

Somehing like this:

```
    class MyFieldManager extends VerticalFieldManager
    {

      int width;
      int height;

      MyFieldManager(int w,int h)
      {
        super(Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL | Manager.HORIZONTAL_SCROLL );
        width=w;
        height=h;
      }

    public void    sublayout(int w,int h)
    {
        super.sublayout(w, h);
        setExtent(width,height);
    }
    }


    BrowserFieldConfig config = new BrowserFieldConfig();  
    config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.ALLOW_CS_XHR, Boolean.TRUE);  
    config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.INITIAL_SCALE, new Float(0.5));
    MyFieldManager m=new MyFieldManager(Display.getWidth()/2,Display.getHeight()/2);
    add(m);
    BrowserField _browserField = new BrowserField(config);
    _browserField.addListener(new InnerBrowserListener());
    m.add(_browserField);
```

I hope this will help you.

This is not my code took from one of the forum, but it is a proven solution :)